# Playing pure sinusoidal tones

Tags: java, audio

I wrote a simple sound player to use as part of my [`MorseString`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75077/follow-up-2-to-morse-code-string) class. I am new to using sounds (in fact, I was helped a lot by Google) and I don't know if this is the correct way to play a sound.

The method takes a specific frequency and a duration as parameters, and plays the frequency for the specified duration.

```
private static final int SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ = 8000;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_FADE_SAMPLES = 80;

private static void sound(int hz, int msecs) throws LineUnavailableException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[msecs * Byte.SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        double angle = i / (SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ / hz) * 2 * Math.PI;
        buf[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * Byte.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FADE_SAMPLES && i < buf.length / 2; i++) {
        buf[i] = (byte) (buf[i] * i / NUMBER_OF_FADE_SAMPLES);
        buf[buf.length - 1 - i] = (byte) (buf[buf.length - 1 - i] * i / NUMBER_OF_FADE_SAMPLES);
    }
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ, Byte.SIZE, 1, true, false);
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    sdl.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.close();
}
```

1. The sound sounds like it is low-quality. Is there a way to improve that?
2. Did I do my math wrong?

Please explain in as much detail as possible, as I'm new and might not understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a sense, your math is wrong.  In

> ```
> double angle = i / (SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ / hz) * 2 * Math.PI;
> ```

… both of the divisions are done using integer arithmetic.  As a result, I get nothing more than a clicking noise.  To get the intended signal, you have to cast `i` to a `double`.  Better yet, write it instead as

```
double angle = 2 * Math.PI * i * hz / SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ;
```

---

By the [Nyquist criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_theorem), a sample rate of 8000 Hz means that you can play a frequency no higher than 4000 Hz.  Therefore, for robustness, you should do one of three things:

- Throw an exception if `hz >= SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ / 2`.
- Let the sampling frequency vary, by setting it to `16 * hz`, for example.
- Set `SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ` high enough so that it covers the range of human hearing (44.1 kHz for CD audio, 48 kHz for DVD video soundtracks).

It would also be wise to define the fade-in / fade-out period as a multiple of the sampling rate.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small glitch (nothing that affects how the code behaves). The multiplier in the `byte[]` size is wrong. It shouldn't be `Byte.SIZE` in that case. In that case it should be `* SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_IN_HZ / 1000`. This happens to be `Byte.SIZE` in case `SAMPLING_REQUENCY_IN_HZ` is `8000`, but that's a coincidence.

Comment: This answer is directly copied from a comment by @ChristianHujer. If he would like to post it again as an answer, I'll delete this placeholder.